# CSS No image for first ul in horizontal menu

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to make a horizontal menu using a ul, with a custom bullet image. But I also want the first menu item to not have the bullet on its left hand side so it looks neat. So that bullets are only appearing in between items, not before the menu items start.

here is what I have so far:

```
#navwrap ul.nav > li > a, #navwrap ul.nav > li .separator {
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #777;
    font-family: Trajan;
    background-image: url('../images/bullet.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#navwrap ul.nav > li > a:hover, #navwrap ul.nav > li .separator:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-image: url('../images/bullet.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

#navwrap ul.nav > li.active > a, #navwrap ul.nav > li.active .separator {
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    background-image: url('../images/bullet.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

I tried adding:

```
#navwrap ul.nav > li:first-child > a, #navwrap ul.nav > li:first-child .separator {
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #777;
        font-family: Trajan;
    background: none;
        padding-left: 25px;
}
#navwrap ul.nav > li:first-child > a:hover, #navwrap ul.nav > li:first-child .separator:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#navwrap ul.nav > li:first-child.active > a, #navwrap ul.nav > li:first-child.active .separator {
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    background: none;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

<strike>Which seemed to work but made the menu 'jump' to the right a bit when I hovered over it.
What is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do without the first item moving when in hover state?</strike>

Thanks JoshC, Removing the `Background:none` from the hover fixed it.

thanks.

Comment: Remove `background:none` ?

Comment: Can you also post your HTML? You can use CSS Pseudo-class first-child then set the property to background:none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `background:none` from the first-child hover fixed it.